# How do I read the velocitystatus of my maxon motor?

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am writing a program in c++ to control an Epos maxon motor with an rs232 communication. I already figured out how to send messages to set the velocity or other settings. 
Now I need to make it rotate for a specific period of time (e.g. 10 seconds) once it has reached its target velocity. apparently it is possible to read the status of the motor and see if the target velocity is reached. the application note sais, that if the bit 10 of the object 0x6041 is set, the target velocity is reached, but I don't know how to read that bit. 
Does anybody know what I have to do? 
Here is the code of how I set the velocity with a specific acceleration:

```
    void DataField::doVelocity(int i) {


    float colTime = fromString<int>(Action[i][1]);                                          //Haltezeit in sekunde
    float frequency = fromString<int>(Action[i][2]);                                        //Drehfrequenz in Hz
    float acceleration = fromString<int>(Action[i][3]);                                     //Beschleunigung in Hz/s

    cout << "Parameter:\t" << colTime << "\t" << frequency << "\t" << acceleration << endl;

    short mode2[8] = { 0x1103,0x6060,0x0100,0x0003,0x0000,0x0000 };                         //velocity mode einstellen
    motorobj.communication(mode2);

    short accel[8] = { 0x1103, 0x6083, 0x0100, acceleration , 0x000, 0x000 };               //Acceleration einstellen NOCH NICHT GETESTET
    motorobj.communication(accel);

    target[1] = { 0x60ff };                                                                 //target velocity index
    target[3] = frequency;


    motorobj.communication(switchon);

    motorobj.communication(target);

    motorobj.communication(control);

    //controlbit abfragen, ob target velocity erreicht ist, wenn ja: velocity Haltezeit lang halten
    Sleep(colTime * 1000);

}
```

This is the class in which I implement all the functions I need for the motor:

```
class motor {
private:
    RS232 *rs232p;
    uint8_t written;
    char *buffer;
public:
    motor(char*buffer, RS232 *rs232);
    ~motor();

    void schreiben(short *Befehl);
    short CalcFieldCRC(short* pDataArray, int numberOfWords);
    void communication(short*Befehl);
    void eingaben(int mode, short*Befehl1, short *Befehl2);

};



motor::motor(char *buffer, RS232 *rs232) : rs232p(rs232), buffer(buffer)        //da rs232 hier als zeiger übergeben wird, kann es allen anderen funktionen ohne "&" übergeben werden
{
    written = 0;
}
motor::~motor()
{
}

void motor::eingaben(int mode, short*position, short *start)
{
    short a, b;
    if (mode == 1)
    {
        cout << "gewuenschte Position eingeben" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        position[3] = a;

        cout << "fuer start rel. position 127 eingeben, fuer absolut position 63" << endl;
        cin >> b;
        start[3] = b;
    }
    else if (mode == 2)
    {
        cout << "gewuenschte Geschwindigkeit eingeben" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        position[3] = a;

        cout << "fuer start 15 eingeben" << endl;
        cin >> b;
        start[3] = b;
    }
}


void motor::schreiben(short *Befehl) {

    Befehl[5] = CalcFieldCRC(&Befehl[0], 6);


    short  a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2;

    a2 = Befehl[0]; //0pCode weglassen
    b1 = Befehl[1];
    b2 = Befehl[1] >> 8;
    c1 = Befehl[2];
    c2 = Befehl[2] >> 8;
    d1 = Befehl[3];
    d2 = Befehl[3] >> 8;
    e1 = Befehl[4];
    e2 = Befehl[4] >> 8;
    f1 = Befehl[5];
    f2 = Befehl[5] >> 8;

    char buffer2[60] = { a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2 };//LSB zuerst übergeben
                                                                      //char buffer[60] = { a2,b2,b1,c2,c1,d2,d1,e2,e1,f2,f1 };
    rs232_write(rs232p, buffer2, 11, &written);
};

void motor::communication(short* Befehl)
{
    char opCode[1] = { 0x11 };      //OpCode für schreiben
    char OK[1] = { 0x4f };

    rs232_write(rs232p, opCode, 1, &written);
    Sleep(100);
    if (buffer[0] == 'O' || buffer[0] == 0x4f)
        schreiben(Befehl);
    else
        cout << "Fehler! Falsche Antowrt" << endl;
    Sleep(100);

    if (buffer[0] == 'O' || buffer[0] == 0x4f)
        rs232_write(rs232p, OK, 1, &written);
    else
        cout << "Fehler! Falsche Antowrt" << endl;
    Sleep(100);


    if (buffer != 0)
        rs232_write(rs232p, OK, 1, &written);
    else
        cout << "Fehler! Falsche Antowrt" << endl;
}


short motor::CalcFieldCRC(short* pDataArray, int numberOfWords)
{
    unsigned short shifter, c;
    bool carry = false;
    short CRC = 0;

    //Calculate pDataArray Word by Word
    while (numberOfWords--)         //solange noch datenwörter vorhanden sind
    {
        shifter = 0x8000;       //=0b1000 0000 0000 0000
        c = *pDataArray++;      //Datenwort i in c kopieren
        do
        {
            carry = CRC & 0x8000;       //carry =1 wenn hoechstes bit von crc gesetzt ist
            CRC <<= 1;                  //CRC=CRC*2
            if (c & shifter) CRC++;     //wenn betrachtetes bit des Datenwortes gesetzt ist, crc+1
            if (carry) CRC ^= 0x1021;       //wenn carry=1, crc XOR polynom
            shifter >>= 1;              //betrachtetes bit nach rechts shiften
        } while (shifter);
    }
    return CRC;
}

#endif
//globale variablen die in allen Funktionen gebraucht werden

uint8_t written;
RS232 rs232;
char buffer[61]; // +1 for the NUL-terminator
motor motorobj(buffer, &rs232);     //motor objekt estellen
```

Comment: What is `motorobj`? Does it have any functions to *read* from the motor? And I'm sorry for maybe sounding rude, but perhaps you should implement such a function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added some code :)